# Having trouble using # and & to define a function

Tags: function-construction

Let's say I want to define a function indexed by an natural number $g$, which is given by
$$f_g(x)=g+x$$

I could (I guess naively) write the following code to define it up until $g=19$

```
For[g = 1, g < 20, g++, f[g] = g + # &]
```

But, for some reason, this doesn't work. If you try to evaluate, let's say

```
f[3]
f[3][10]
```

you see that the use of # delays the replacement of $g$ until you give the function an argument. $f_3(10)$ above returns $30$ for example, since that's the value of $g$ at that point in the code.

Now, I am aware I could just define a two-variable function (I think that's actually doable in the original problem I'm working on too) but I would still like to understand what is going on here and how I can get around this without actually avoiding the problem altogether.

Thank you all.

Comment: Looking at your first equation: f3(10) should be 3+10=13? But later on you want it evaluated as 30?

Comment: I didn't want it evaluated as $30$, but it does so anyway. I wanted $13$, which is not what happens with the above code. This specific question got solved in the answer below, but the solution doesn't quite work for my original code, so I asked a new question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266133/unable-to-properly-define-an-operator-indexed-by-a-natural-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhat interesting what exactly gets held here (as in `Hold`). The anonymous function holds its arguments unevaluated, so:

```
For[g = 1, g < 20, g++, f[g] = g + # &]
```

Assigns `g + # &` to `f[1]` through `f[19]`, in exactly the form.

You could change this to:

```
For[g = 1, g < 20, g++, f[g] = Evaluate[g + #] &]
```

And it will subsequently work, as `f[1]` becomes `1 + # &`, `f[2]` becomes `2 + # &` and so on. Note that operator precedence around `Evaluate` and `&` can be somewhat non-intuitive. For example, `(Evaluate[g] + #) &` gives a somewhat unexpected form which holds the `Evaluate` term in its entirety. I suspect this may be explained somewhere, but I've not personally encountered where.

More generically, you may also want to consider one of the following:

```
f[g_] := g + # &
f[g_?IntegerQ] := g + # &
```

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for, some way to "force" the evaluation to take precedence, but I couldn't figure it out myself. Thank you!

Comment: Never mind, it still doesn't work for my original problem. Evaluate just stays there and doesn't do anything. I've asked a new question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266133/unable-to-properly-define-an-operator-indexed-by-a-natural-number) with exactly the problem that I'm facing.

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this is what you intended?

[image]

Comment: Yes that works too. And thank you for that neat "indexed argument" notation, which I did not know :)

Comment: Nice and new to me too. Is there any hidden problem with this as I read that people try to avoid subscript whenever you can?

Comment: `Subscript[f, 1][x] // Head` returns `Plus`. And should it not have returned `f1`?