# Unable to properly define an operator indexed by a natural number

Tags: function-construction

I'm trying to define a differential operator indexed by a natural number $n$, with the definition varying depending on the parity of $n$. Here's what I wrote:

```
For[g = 3, g <= 10, g++,
 If[EvenQ[g], Dop[g] = -dF[g/2]*D[#, x] &, 
  Dop[g] = A'[z] dF[(g + 1)/2]*# &]
 ]
```

where `dF` is just a function that receives an integer argument. The problem here is that the argument of `dF` does not get evaluated until after when I give the operator itself an argument.

For instance if, right after the `For`, one evaluates `Dop[1][f[x]]`, we see that it's using $g=11$. I tried using `Evaluate` as suggested [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266126/having-trouble-using-and-to-define-a-function/266129#2661299), but it still doesn't work. For example

```
For[g = 3, g <= 10, g++,
 If[EvenQ[g], Dop[g] = -dF[Evaluate[g/2]]*D[#, x] &, 
  Dop[g] = A'[z] dF[Evaluate[(g + 1)/2]]*# &]
 ]
```

does not do anything and

```
For[g = 3, g <= 10, g++,
 If[EvenQ[g], Dop[g] = Evaluate[-dF[g/2]*D[#, x]] &, 
  Dop[g] = Evaluate[A'[z] dF[(g + 1)/2]*#] &]
 ]
```

only works in the odd case. In the even case, I'm assuming it is forcing the derivative to be done right away, because the operator vanishes.

There was also the suggestion of using SetDelayed instead of a `For` in the above answer, but `Dop[1]` and `Dop[2]` have different definitions, so I'm not sure how to do that without overwritting these (notice that the `For`s only start on $g=3$).

I'd appreciate any insight here. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just use: `Dop[g_Integer] := 
 If[EvenQ[g], -dF[g/2] D[#, x] &, A'[z] dF[(g + 1)/2] # &]`?

Comment: I just edited and added the last paragraph saying that the definition is different for $g=1$ and $g=2$, and made the loops start only at $3$, sorry for that. This was actually the original motivation to do a ```For``` loop, I guess.

Could I possibly just write ```Dop[1]=``` and ```Dop[2]=``` after what you wrote to overwrite the definition?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to provide specific instances to override the general cases.

Comment: I tried. The overwritting works fine but ```Dop[4][f[x]]``` the even case does not seem to work very well.

Comment: Actually, yes it does, I apologize. Thank you!

Comment: @CarlWoll I will say though, the solution still slightly bothers me, because if the operator had an iterative definition on the index for example, it could be very complicated to solve it like this. Do you have a suggestion on how one could proceed then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what you definitions are:

```
For[g = 3, g <= 10, g++, 
 If[EvenQ[g], Dop[g] = -dF[g/2]*D[#, x] &, 
  Dop[g] = A'[z] dF[(g + 1)/2]*# &]]
?? Dop
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

You see that "g" in the code of the function is not evaluated. The reason is, that "Function" or "&" has the attribute "HoldFirst". You can override this by "Evaluate", but this does not give the expected result. E.g.:

```
Dop[g] = Evaluate[-dF[Evaluate[g/2]]*D[#, x]] &
(* 0 & *)
```

It gives the zero function. The reason is that evaluating D[#x,] gives zero because "#" is not a function of "x".

The solution is to use "With". This statement replaces names by values that are evaluated. e.g. With[{g=g},...], it first  evaluates g (on the right side) and replaces every occurrence of the variable g (on the left side) by the evaluated value:

```
For[g = 3, g <= 10, 
 g++ If[EvenQ[g], With[{g = g}, Dop[g] = -dF[g/2]*D[#, x] &] , 
   Dop[g] = A'[z] With[{g = g}, dF[(g + 1)/2]*# &]]]
?? Dop
```

[image]

As you can see, now "g" in the body of the function is evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The operator could also be defined succintly using patterns instead of a `For` loop.

```
Clear[Dop]
Dop[1] = gfun[1];
Dop[2] = gfun[2];
Dop[g_?EvenQ] := -dF[g/2] D[#, x] &
Dop[g_?OddQ] := A'[z] dF[(g + 1)/2]*# &

Table[Dop[n][f[x]], {n, 10}] // Column
```

$\begin{array}{l}
 \text{gfun}(1)(f(x)) \\
 \text{gfun}(2)(f(x)) \\
 \text{dF}(2) f(x) A'(z) \\
 -\text{dF}(2) f'(x) \\
 \text{dF}(3) f(x) A'(z) \\
 -\text{dF}(3) f'(x) \\
 \text{dF}(4) f(x) A'(z) \\
 -\text{dF}(4) f'(x) \\
 \text{dF}(5) f(x) A'(z) \\
 -\text{dF}(5) f'(x) \\
\end{array}$

Comment: This is great as well, thank you very much!